# How do I URLencode only part of a concatenated string in AppleScript

Tags: applescript, urlencode

Trying to create a service that will translate selected text using https://translate.google.com.

When I select a piece of text like "Please" it works perfectly and generates the URL:
https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=da&text=Please

When I select a piece of text like "Please help me" it generates the URL:
https://translate.google.com/%23view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=da&text=Please%20help%20me
and this doesn't work. The whole URL is getting URLEncoded i guess. The "#" (hashtag) at ".com/#view" is converted to "%23" and I think this is the problem.

How do I URLEncode only the variable "input"?

```
on run {input, parameters}
    
    set thelist to {"Afrikaans", "Albansk", "Amharisk", "Arabisk", "Armensk", "Aserbajdsjansk", "Baskisk", "Bengali", "Bosnisk", "Bulgarsk", "Burmesisk", "Cebuano", "Chichewa", "Dansk", "Engelsk", "Esperanto", "Estisk", "Finsk", "Fransk", "Frisisk", "Galicisk", "Georgisk", "Græsk", "Gujarati", "Haitisk kreolsk", "Hausa", "Hawaiiansk", "Hebraisk", "Hindi", "Hmong", "Hollandsk", "Hviderussisk", "Igbo", "Indonesisk", "Irsk", "Islandsk", "Italiensk", "Japansk", "Javanesisk", "Jiddisch", "Kannada", "Kasakhisk", "Katalansk", "Khmer", "Kinesisk (forenklet)", "Kinesisk (traditionelt)", "Kinyarwanda", "Kirgisk", "Koreansk", "Korsikansk", "Kroatisk", "Kurdisk", "Laotisk", "Latin", "Lettisk", "Litauisk", "Luxembourgsk", "Makedonsk", "Malagassisk", "Malajisk", "Malayalam", "Maltesisk", "Maori", "Marathi", "Mongolsk", "Nepalesisk", "Norsk", "Odia (Oriya)", "Pashto", "Persisk", "Polsk", "Portugisisk", "Punjabi", "Rumænsk", "Russisk", "Samoansk", "Serbisk", "Sesotho", "Shona", "Sindhi", "Sinhala", "Skotsk gælisk", "Slovakisk", "Slovensk", "Somalisk", "Spansk", "Sundanesisk", "Svensk", "Swahili", "Tadsjikisk", "Tagalog", "Tamil", "Tatarisk", "Telugu", "Thailandsk", "Tjekkisk", "Turkmensk", "Tyrkisk", "Tysk", "Uighursk", "Ukrainsk", "Ungarsk", "Urdu", "Usbekisk", "Vietnamesisk", "Walisisk", "Xhosa", "Yoruba", "Zulu"}
    set theItem to choose from list thelist with prompt "Hvad vil du oversætte til?" default items {"Dansk"}
    
    if theItem = {"Afrikaans"} then
        set language to "af"
    else if theItem = {"Albansk"} then
        set language to "sq"
    else if theItem = {"Amharisk"} then
        set language to "am"
    else if theItem = {"Arabisk"} then
        set language to "ar"
    else if theItem = {"Armensk"} then
        set language to "hy"
    else if theItem = {"Aserbajdsjansk"} then
        set language to "az"
    else if theItem = {"Baskisk"} then
        set language to "eu"
    else if theItem = {"Bengali"} then
        set language to "bn"
    else if theItem = {"Bosnisk"} then
        set language to "bs"
    else if theItem = {"Bulgarsk"} then
        set language to "bg"
    else if theItem = {"Burmesisk"} then
        set language to "my"
    else if theItem = {"Cebuano"} then
        set language to "ceb"
    else if theItem = {"Chichewa"} then
        set language to "ny"
    else if theItem = {"Dansk"} then
        set language to "da"
    else if theItem = {"Engelsk"} then
        set language to "en"
    else if theItem = {"Esperanto"} then
        set language to "eo"
    else if theItem = {"Estisk"} then
        set language to "et"
    else if theItem = {"Finsk"} then
        set language to "fi"
    else if theItem = {"Fransk"} then
        set language to "fr"
    else if theItem = {"Frisisk"} then
        set language to "fy"
    else if theItem = {"Galicisk"} then
        set language to "gl"
    else if theItem = {"Georgisk"} then
        set language to "ka"
    else if theItem = {"Græsk"} then
        set language to "el"
    else if theItem = {"Haitisk kreolsk"} then
        set language to "ht"
    else if theItem = {"Hausa"} then
        set language to "ha"
    else if theItem = {"Hawaiiansk"} then
        set language to "haw"
    else if theItem = {"Hebraisk"} then
        set language to "iw"
    else if theItem = {"Hindi"} then
        set language to "hi"
    else if theItem = {"Hmong"} then
        set language to "hmn"
    else if theItem = {"Hollandsk"} then
        set language to "nl"
    else if theItem = {"Hviderussisk"} then
        set language to "be"
    else if theItem = {"Igbo"} then
        set language to "ig"
    else if theItem = {"Indonesisk"} then
        set language to "id"
    else if theItem = {"Irsk"} then
        set language to "ga"
    else if theItem = {"Islandsk"} then
        set language to "is"
    else if theItem = {"Italiensk"} then
        set language to "it"
    else if theItem = {"Japansk"} then
        set language to "ja"
    else if theItem = {"Javanesisk"} then
        set language to "jw"
    else if theItem = {"Jiddisch"} then
        set language to "yi"
    else if theItem = {"Kannada"} then
        set language to "kn"
    else if theItem = {"Kasakhisk"} then
        set language to "kk"
    else if theItem = {"Katalansk"} then
        set language to "ca"
    else if theItem = {"Khmer"} then
        set language to "km"
    else if theItem = {"Kinesisk (forenklet)"} then
        set language to "zh-CN"
    else if theItem = {"Kinesisk (traditionelt)"} then
        set language to "zh-TW"
    else if theItem = {"Kinyarwanda"} then
        set language to "rw"
    else if theItem = {"Kirgisk"} then
        set language to "ky"
    else if theItem = {"Koreansk"} then
        set language to "ko"
    else if theItem = {"Korsikansk"} then
        set language to "co"
    else if theItem = {"Kroatisk"} then
        set language to "hr"
    else if theItem = {"Kurdisk"} then
        set language to "ku"
    else if theItem = {"Laotisk"} then
        set language to "lo"
    else if theItem = {"Latin"} then
        set language to "la"
    else if theItem = {"Lettisk"} then
        set language to "lv"
    else if theItem = {"Litauisk"} then
        set language to "lt"
    else if theItem = {"Luxembourgsk"} then
        set language to "lb"
    else if theItem = {"Malagassisk"} then
        set language to "mg"
    else if theItem = {"Malayalam"} then
        set language to "ml"
    else if theItem = {"Maltesisk"} then
        set language to "mt"
    else if theItem = {"Maori"} then
        set language to "mi"
    else if theItem = {"Marathi"} then
        set language to "mr"
    else if theItem = {"Mongolsk"} then
        set language to "mn"
    else if theItem = {"Nepalesisk"} then
        set language to "ne"
    else if theItem = {"Norsk"} then
        set language to "no"
    else if theItem = {"Odia (Oriya)"} then
        set language to "or"
    else if theItem = {"Pashto"} then
        set language to "ps"
    else if theItem = {"Persisk"} then
        set language to "fa"
    else if theItem = {"Polsk"} then
        set language to "pl"
    else if theItem = {"Portugisisk"} then
        set language to "pt"
    else if theItem = {"Punjabi"} then
        set language to "pa"
    else if theItem = {"Rumænsk"} then
        set language to "ro"
    else if theItem = {"Russisk"} then
        set language to "ru"
    else if theItem = {"Samoansk"} then
        set language to "sm"
    else if theItem = {"Serbisk"} then
        set language to "sr"
    else if theItem = {"Sesotho"} then
        set language to "st"
    else if theItem = {"Shona"} then
        set language to "sn"
    else if theItem = {"Sindhi"} then
        set language to "sd"
    else if theItem = {"Sinhala"} then
        set language to "si"
    else if theItem = {"Skotsk gælisk"} then
        set language to "gd"
    else if theItem = {"Slovakisk"} then
        set language to "sk"
    else if theItem = {"Slovensk"} then
        set language to "sl"
    else if theItem = {"Somalisk"} then
        set language to "so"
    else if theItem = {"Spansk"} then
        set language to "es"
    else if theItem = {"Sundanesisk"} then
        set language to "su"
    else if theItem = {"Svensk"} then
        set language to "sv"
    else if theItem = {"Swahili"} then
        set language to "sw"
    else if theItem = {"Tadsjikisk"} then
        set language to "tg"
    else if theItem = {"Tagalog"} then
        set language to "tl"
    else if theItem = {"Tamil"} then
        set language to "ta"
    else if theItem = {"Tatarisk"} then
        set language to "tt"
    else if theItem = {"Telugu"} then
        set language to "te"
    else if theItem = {"Thailandsk"} then
        set language to "th"
    else if theItem = {"Tjekkisk"} then
        set language to "cs"
    else if theItem = {"Turkmensk"} then
        set language to "tk"
    else if theItem = {"Tyrkisk"} then
        set language to "tr"
    else if theItem = {"Tysk"} then
        set language to "de"
    else if theItem = {"Uighursk"} then
        set language to "ug"
    else if theItem = {"Ukrainsk"} then
        set language to "uk"
    else if theItem = {"Ungarsk"} then
        set language to "hu"
    else if theItem = {"Urdu"} then
        set language to "ur"
    else if theItem = {"Usbekisk"} then
        set language to "uz"
    else if theItem = {"Vietnamesisk"} then
        set language to "vi"
    else if theItem = {"Walisisk"} then
        set language to "cy"
    else if theItem = {"Xhosa"} then
        set language to "xh"
    else if theItem = {"Yoruba"} then
        set language to "yo"
    else if theItem = {"Zulu"} then
        set language to "zu"
    end if
    
    open location "https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=" & language & "&text=" & input
    
    
end run
```

Comment: When someone has an issue with **AppleScript** run from **Automator** the first thing I do is run the _code_ from **Script Editor** as it's easier to debug. The first issue is with the use of `language` it produces **Syntax Error** "Can’t set «class lang» to "af". Access not allowed.", so I changed it to `lang`. The **URL** run by `open location` is then `https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=da&text=Please%20help%20me` but in **Automator** it's as in your OP. I'd do two things... 1. Change `language` to `lang` or `|language|` 2. Encode the `input` Cont...

Comment: Have a look at [Encoding and Decoding Text](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/EncodeandDecodeText.html) Using information in this link I was able to in **Automator** _encode_ the `input` in the **Run AppleScript** _action_ and open the properly formed **URL**.

Comment: I've added both `encodeCharacter(theCharacter)` and `encodeText(theText, encodeCommonSpecialCharacters, encodeExtendedSpecialCharacters)` and changed `open location...` to
`open location "https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=" & lang & "&text=" & encodeText(input, false, false)` and now it only takes the first character of the selected text.

Comment: The `encodeText()` _handler_ is expecting _text_ and `input` is a _list_ and needs to be coerced into a _string_ (or _text_, which is the same thing). If you use `encodeText(input as string, false, false)` it will return the entire _selected test_.

Comment: Wow, totally on the right track – thanks.  But when I E.g. select your first comment on my question it seems to have trouble with the double quotes

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question. However, I have a completely different approach that you may actually prefer. Basically this approach will take the text that you have a copied to your clipboard and translate it for you… to the language you have chosen. It will then show you your translated text in a dialog pop up and will also copy the translation to your clipboard.

This following animation demonstrates the process. I will trigger the translation script with a keyboard shortcut that I created in the Services Preferences.

[image]

**Getting Started:**

1. Homebrew needs to be installed on your system. If it is not
   installed, you can find step by step instructions for its
   installation… here —> [Install Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)
2. After successful installation of Homebrew, you will need to install
   the `translate-shell` formula.  Paste this in a macOS Terminal or
   Linux shell prompt. `brew install translate-shell`
3. After successful installation of the Homebrew `translate-shell`
   formula, the `trans` command has tons of options. Paste this in a
   macOS Terminal shell prompt `man trans` to learn about its features.
4. Now you can incorporate your "Translation" code into an Automator
   Quick Action then assign it a keyboard shortcut in your Services
   Preferences. You can read exactly how to use the `trans` shell
   script command with AppleScript here ---> [Run Translate Shell from
   an AppleScript](https://github.com/soimort/translate-shell/wiki/AppleScript)

Here is the code I used in Script Editor and Automator

```
copy (the clipboard) to theText

delay 0.1

set detectedLanguage to (do shell script "export PATH=\"/usr/local/bin:$PATH\";/usr/local/bin/trans -identify -no-ansi " & quoted form of theText & " | " & "grep Name " & "| " & "cut -c 23-")

set theList to {"Afrikaans", "Albansk", "Amharisk", "Arabisk", "Armensk", "Aserbajdsjansk", "Baskisk", "Bengali", "Bosnisk", "Bulgarsk", "Burmesisk", "Cebuano", "Chichewa", "Dansk", "Engelsk", "Esperanto", "Estisk", "Finsk", "Fransk", "Frisisk", "Galicisk", "Georgisk", "Græsk", "Gujarati", "Haitisk kreolsk", "Hausa", "Hawaiiansk", "Hebraisk", "Hindi", "Hmong", "Hollandsk", "Hviderussisk", "Igbo", "Indonesisk", "Irsk", "Islandsk", "Italiensk", "Japansk", "Javanesisk", "Jiddisch", "Kannada", "Kasakhisk", "Katalansk", "Khmer", "Kinesisk (forenklet)", "Kinesisk (traditionelt)", "Kinyarwanda", "Kirgisk", "Koreansk", "Korsikansk", "Kroatisk", "Kurdisk", "Laotisk", "Latin", "Lettisk", "Litauisk", "Luxembourgsk", "Makedonsk", "Malagassisk", "Malajisk", "Malayalam", "Maltesisk", "Maori", "Marathi", "Mongolsk", "Nepalesisk", "Norsk", "Odia (Oriya)", "Pashto", "Persisk", "Polsk", "Portugisisk", "Punjabi", "Rumænsk", "Russisk", "Samoansk", "Serbisk", "Sesotho", "Shona", "Sindhi", "Sinhala", "Skotsk gælisk", "Slovakisk", "Slovensk", "Somalisk", "Spansk", "Sundanesisk", "Svensk", "Swahili", "Tadsjikisk", "Tagalog", "Tamil", "Tatarisk", "Telugu", "Thailandsk", "Tjekkisk", "Turkmensk", "Tyrkisk", "Tysk", "Uighursk", "Ukrainsk", "Ungarsk", "Urdu", "Usbekisk", "Vietnamesisk", "Walisisk", "Xhosa", "Yoruba", "Zulu"}

activate
set theItem to choose from list theList with prompt "What Language Do You Want To Translate To?" default items {"Engelsk"}

if theItem = {"Afrikaans"} then
    set theLanguage to "af"
else if theItem = {"Albansk"} then
    set theLanguage to "sq"
else if theItem = {"Amharisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "am"
else if theItem = {"Arabisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "ar"
else if theItem = {"Armensk"} then
    set theLanguage to "hy"
else if theItem = {"Aserbajdsjansk"} then
    set theLanguage to "az"
else if theItem = {"Baskisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "eu"
else if theItem = {"Bengali"} then
    set theLanguage to "bn"
else if theItem = {"Bosnisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "bs"
else if theItem = {"Bulgarsk"} then
    set theLanguage to "bg"
else if theItem = {"Burmesisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "my"
else if theItem = {"Cebuano"} then
    set theLanguage to "ceb"
else if theItem = {"Chichewa"} then
    set theLanguage to "ny"
else if theItem = {"Dansk"} then
    set theLanguage to "da"
else if theItem = {"Engelsk"} then
    set theLanguage to "en"
else if theItem = {"Esperanto"} then
    set theLanguage to "eo"
else if theItem = {"Estisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "et"
else if theItem = {"Finsk"} then
    set theLanguage to "fi"
else if theItem = {"Fransk"} then
    set theLanguage to "fr"
else if theItem = {"Frisisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "fy"
else if theItem = {"Galicisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "gl"
else if theItem = {"Georgisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "ka"
else if theItem = {"Græsk"} then
    set theLanguage to "el"
else if theItem = {"Haitisk kreolsk"} then
    set theLanguage to "ht"
else if theItem = {"Hausa"} then
    set theLanguage to "ha"
else if theItem = {"Hawaiiansk"} then
    set theLanguage to "haw"
else if theItem = {"Hebraisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "iw"
else if theItem = {"Hindi"} then
    set theLanguage to "hi"
else if theItem = {"Hmong"} then
    set theLanguage to "hmn"
else if theItem = {"Hollandsk"} then
    set theLanguage to "nl"
else if theItem = {"Hviderussisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "be"
else if theItem = {"Igbo"} then
    set theLanguage to "ig"
else if theItem = {"Indonesisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "id"
else if theItem = {"Irsk"} then
    set theLanguage to "ga"
else if theItem = {"Islandsk"} then
    set theLanguage to "is"
else if theItem = {"Italiensk"} then
    set theLanguage to "it"
else if theItem = {"Japansk"} then
    set theLanguage to "ja"
else if theItem = {"Javanesisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "jw"
else if theItem = {"Jiddisch"} then
    set theLanguage to "yi"
else if theItem = {"Kannada"} then
    set theLanguage to "kn"
else if theItem = {"Kasakhisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "kk"
else if theItem = {"Katalansk"} then
    set theLanguage to "ca"
else if theItem = {"Khmer"} then
    set theLanguage to "km"
else if theItem = {"Kinesisk (forenklet)"} then
    set theLanguage to "zh-CN"
else if theItem = {"Kinesisk (traditionelt)"} then
    set theLanguage to "zh-TW"
else if theItem = {"Kinyarwanda"} then
    set theLanguage to "rw"
else if theItem = {"Kirgisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "ky"
else if theItem = {"Koreansk"} then
    set theLanguage to "ko"
else if theItem = {"Korsikansk"} then
    set theLanguage to "co"
else if theItem = {"Kroatisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "hr"
else if theItem = {"Kurdisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "ku"
else if theItem = {"Laotisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "lo"
else if theItem = {"Latin"} then
    set theLanguage to "la"
else if theItem = {"Lettisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "lv"
else if theItem = {"Litauisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "lt"
else if theItem = {"Luxembourgsk"} then
    set theLanguage to "lb"
else if theItem = {"Malagassisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "mg"
else if theItem = {"Malayalam"} then
    set theLanguage to "ml"
else if theItem = {"Maltesisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "mt"
else if theItem = {"Maori"} then
    set theLanguage to "mi"
else if theItem = {"Marathi"} then
    set theLanguage to "mr"
else if theItem = {"Mongolsk"} then
    set theLanguage to "mn"
else if theItem = {"Nepalesisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "ne"
else if theItem = {"Norsk"} then
    set theLanguage to "no"
else if theItem = {"Odia (Oriya)"} then
    set theLanguage to "or"
else if theItem = {"Pashto"} then
    set theLanguage to "ps"
else if theItem = {"Persisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "fa"
else if theItem = {"Polsk"} then
    set theLanguage to "pl"
else if theItem = {"Portugisisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "pt"
else if theItem = {"Punjabi"} then
    set theLanguage to "pa"
else if theItem = {"Rumænsk"} then
    set theLanguage to "ro"
else if theItem = {"Russisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "ru"
else if theItem = {"Samoansk"} then
    set theLanguage to "sm"
else if theItem = {"Serbisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "sr"
else if theItem = {"Sesotho"} then
    set theLanguage to "st"
else if theItem = {"Shona"} then
    set theLanguage to "sn"
else if theItem = {"Sindhi"} then
    set theLanguage to "sd"
else if theItem = {"Sinhala"} then
    set theLanguage to "si"
else if theItem = {"Skotsk gælisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "gd"
else if theItem = {"Slovakisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "sk"
else if theItem = {"Slovensk"} then
    set theLanguage to "sl"
else if theItem = {"Somalisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "so"
else if theItem = {"Spansk"} then
    set theLanguage to "es"
else if theItem = {"Sundanesisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "su"
else if theItem = {"Svensk"} then
    set theLanguage to "sv"
else if theItem = {"Swahili"} then
    set theLanguage to "sw"
else if theItem = {"Tadsjikisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "tg"
else if theItem = {"Tagalog"} then
    set theLanguage to "tl"
else if theItem = {"Tamil"} then
    set theLanguage to "ta"
else if theItem = {"Tatarisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "tt"
else if theItem = {"Telugu"} then
    set theLanguage to "te"
else if theItem = {"Thailandsk"} then
    set theLanguage to "th"
else if theItem = {"Tjekkisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "cs"
else if theItem = {"Turkmensk"} then
    set theLanguage to "tk"
else if theItem = {"Tyrkisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "tr"
else if theItem = {"Tysk"} then
    set theLanguage to "de"
else if theItem = {"Uighursk"} then
    set theLanguage to "ug"
else if theItem = {"Ukrainsk"} then
    set theLanguage to "uk"
else if theItem = {"Ungarsk"} then
    set theLanguage to "hu"
else if theItem = {"Urdu"} then
    set theLanguage to "ur"
else if theItem = {"Usbekisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "uz"
else if theItem = {"Vietnamesisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "vi"
else if theItem = {"Walisisk"} then
    set theLanguage to "cy"
else if theItem = {"Xhosa"} then
    set theLanguage to "xh"
else if theItem = {"Yoruba"} then
    set theLanguage to "yo"
else if theItem = {"Zulu"} then
    set theLanguage to "zu"
end if

set theTranslation to (do shell script "export PATH=\"/usr/local/bin:$PATH\";/usr/local/bin/trans -b :" & theLanguage & " " & quoted form of theText)

set the clipboard to theTranslation

activate
display dialog "The Translation Has Been Copied To The Clipboard For Your Convenience" & linefeed & linefeed & theTranslation with title "Your Translation Results From " & detectedLanguage & " To " & theItem buttons {"OK"}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a cool solution for anyone having Homebrew installed. My intension is to share my service with non techie people and they don't have Homebrew. Thanks for the inspiration, though – think I'll copy it and use it myself.